# Microsoft service fabric 3.3.65, won't install , Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Attempting to install Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK 3.3.65 in order to build a stateless ASP.Net Core' microservice with Visual Studio 2019 'Community Edition' The runtime 6.5 installs fine via the web Platform' installer, however the Service Fabric SDK 3.3.65 will not. The Error. 'External Dependency is Not Installed' Visual Studio 2015 Update' .. would probably be an easy fix, if not for the fact.. running VStudio 2019 [Visual Studio Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXBgK.png)

Comment: Have you had previously installed Visual Studio 2015? It would be useful to post the installation log.

Comment: no,ever had 2015.. new machine, with win10 Pro, not running docker or anything else.. that should impede install.. also did a repair on VStudio 2019..